# Chess board to list

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

So I have a picture of a chess board and I have pictures of pieces and tiles, and now I need to figure out how to translate the data from an image into a board list (8x8 list where pieces that are on the image would be correctly positioned). I managed to use opencv to select the whole board from the given image but I can't figure out how to check for pieces from given the given images.

Ideally I wouldn't use opencv and would like to get it done with Pillow or imageio

```
import cv2
large_image = cv2.imread('checkmate_public/public/set/1/1.png') 
cv2.imshow('output',large_image)
```

I've heard about templating but I'm not sure what functions would be used in libraries like Pillow or imageio